# Angular 6 theming : How do i set background color and use in entire app

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, themes

I have theme.scss file in which i have set the colors  like below :

```js
/* mat-palette accepts $palette-name, main, lighter and darker variants */

@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$gims-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue,500,900,A100);
$gims-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-yellow, 500, A200, A100);
$gims-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red,500,900,A100);

$gims-app-theme: mat-light-theme($gims-app-primary, $gims-app-accent, $gims-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($gims-app-theme);
```

I need to declare a background color here and use it in entire app.
Since i will be implementing light and dark theme , the background color should be configurable. 
Any idea how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from primary, accent and warn palettes, material themes also have foreground and background palettes (as mentioned on the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#what-is-a-theme-)). Still, there are no examples on the official docs.

There is a discussion on Github regarding adding these documents, and I think the following [comment](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6244#issuecomment-361093773), which also has a link to a stackblitz example, may help you with that.

Another way of defining colours once and using it by reference across your entire app is using CSS variables, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Basic_usage). In this case, you may include the variables on styles.css file, using :root selector:

```
:root {
  --blue-1: #0055AA;
}
```